# Why does image source not change immidately after loaded from "URL.createObjectURL()"

Tags: javascript, html, image

I wrote some code for image pixel manipulation. However, I found a strange issue. After loading a image from a local file, I have to add a short "sleep" before loading the image into a canvas, or the previous image  (Firefox) /  a null will be loaded into the canvas(Edge). Can someone tell me why this happened? Thanks. Code is here:

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image Grey Scale Noise</title>
</head>

<body>
  <label for="Selector">Select Image</label>
  <br />
  <input type="file" id="Selector" multiple=false accept="image/*">
  <br />
  <br />
  <label for="greyScale">Grey Scale</label>
  <br />

  <input type="range" id="greyScale" min="0.1" max="10" value="4" step="0.1">

  <p>Image:</p>
  <img id="srcImg" crossOrigin="" src="https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/67770686?s=400&u=24015d89e8fab0fb45cad0be3d282f6062e45b5b&v=4" />
  <br />
  <img id="outImg" crossOrigin="" src="" />
  <script>
    const fileSelector = document.getElementById('Selector');
    const greyScaleSelector = document.getElementById('greyScale')
    const srcImg = document.getElementById('srcImg');
    const outImg = document.getElementById('outImg');
    var c = document.createElement("Canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    async function getNewImage(result, greyScale) {
      srcImg.src = result;
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100)); //Without this, the previous image will be loaded...
      c.height = srcImg.height;
      c.width = srcImg.width;
      ctx.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0);
      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
      const data = imageData.data
      var l = data.length;
      for (i = 0; i < l; i += 4) {
        var r = Math.random() / greyScale + (1 - 1 / greyScale) //Grey Scale Change
        data[i] = Math.min(data[i] * r, 255);
        data[i + 1] = Math.min(data[i + 1] * r, 255);
        data[i + 2] = Math.min(data[i + 2] * r, 255);
      }
      ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
      outImg.src = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
    fileSelector.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
      var greyScale = greyScaleSelector.value;
      var result = URL.createObjectURL(fileSelector.files[0]);
      await getNewImage(result, greyScale);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(result);
    })
    greyScaleSelector.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
      var greyScale = greyScaleSelector.value;
      var result = srcImg.src;
      await getNewImage(result, greyScale);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it sounds like a timing issue: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-document-ready-plain-javascript/ are you sure the browser is "ready" before your JS runs?

Comment: @akaphenom Hi akaphenom, thanks for the timely reply! I was wondering if you would like to comment if my understanding is not correct. URL.createObjectURL() may need some time to complete, and I should call it as a promise or hooked to something like "DOMContentLoaded" events?

Comment: Chaining of of DOM loaded events is best practice as it rules out some of the racde condition bugs.  If you add that and it doen't help - then your problem is elsewhere - but the DOM loaded stuff shouldn't hurt your code - only help it

Comment: why don't you post your solution as an answer?